# Passing an empty Delegate to a method in c#

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to understand how to call a method by passing as parameter an empty delegate function. Into details, the method I need to call is defined as:

```
private async Task<Tuple<VerifiedResult<IEnumerable<T>>, string >> SendRequest<T>(string url, string message, Func<IDictionary<string, string>, T> resultFunc) where T : new()
{
...
}
```

By giving you a working example, in some parts of my code I call this method (for example) in this way:

```
var result = await SendRequest(dataSource.Location, soapTemplate, r => 
        new RetrievePersonResponse
        {
            Id = r["PersonId"],
            Name = r["Name"]
        });
```

No need to explain what the **SendRequest** method does, but it uses the **resultFunc** that I pass to do some extra logic.
However, in a certain case that method returns before that **Func** is called. Therefore I need to call the **SendRequest** method by passing an empty function.

I tried:

```
 await SendRequest(dataSource.Location, soapTemplate, () => { });
```

But the compilation error I receive is: "the type arguments for the method SendRequest cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitely". How can I pass an empty Func when I call the **SendRequest** method?

Comment: Don't you just need `r => null`? Where your method is getting called, it is expecting an object to be returned. Hopefully null will suffice, but there's no getting around that otherwise without editing where it is used.

Comment: Sounds like there should be two overloads of `SendRequest`, one that produces a result, and one that doesn't, with signatures to match.

Comment: @TyCobb That would break type inference.

Comment: @Servy Ah yes. Then to the trenches he goes!

Comment: If you want to keep type inference, just need to pass `x => default(T)`, e.g. `x => default(VerifiedResult<string>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the delegate is:

```
Func<IDictionary<string, string>, T> resultFunc
```

Note the generic arguments. These define the signature of methods or lambdas that you use to create the delegate.

The final argument, `T` is the return type of the delegate. The other arguments are parameters of the delegate. So, this is expecting a method with the signature:

```
T Foo(IDictionary<string,string> dict);
```

When you use lambdas, their parameter types and return types are inferred based on what you're assigning the lambda to and what you're returning. You must ensure your lambda is compatible with the same signature.

tl;dr Modify your lambda to take an argument and return something, like `_ => 0`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep type inference, just need to pass `x => default(T)`, e.g. `x => default(VerifiedResult<string>)`. In context it would look like this:

```
var result = await SendRequest
(
    dataSource.Location, 
    soapTemplate, 
    x => default(SomeSpecificReponseClass<SomeType>)
);
```